# Bringing up pictures from a database as I search for the name

Tags: c#, sql, search

I need help with this program I'm trying to write. I'm a complete noob at this, so forgive my shortcomings but I'm trying to create a search feature, in which it completes the names from a database as soon as you write the first letter. I've done this succesfully, now I have to bring up pictures also from the same database, I'm getting some errors. Could you take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong? And also is this enough?

note: My aim is to bring up pictures AS they write the name.

```
     void showpic(string queryStr)
        {   
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server adress");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand execute = new SqlCommand("SELECT Pernr from View_PhoneBook where DisplayName=" + textBox1.Text, conn);
        try
        {
            StringCollection View_Phonebook = new StringCollection();
            SqlDataReader reader = execute.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                View_Phonebook.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation.Equals("url" + View_Phonebook + ".jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showpic(textBox1.Text);           
    }
```

Comment: You're leaving yourself open to SQL Injection by using this Statement 'new SqlCommand("SELECT Pernr from View_PhoneBook where DisplayName=" + textBox1.Text'. You should use a SQLCommand Parameter. More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I get the "there's no column named "x"" when I try and enter a name in my textbox where I search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes to the string in this line, like so:

```
SqlCommand execute = new SqlCommand('SELECT Pernr from View_PhoneBook where DisplayName= @text', conn);

execute.Parameters.Add("text", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Textbox1.text;
```

Comment: This should solve your 'there's no column named "x"' problem!  The SQL thinks that the Textbox1.text is a column, not a string, in your original implementation. ;)

Comment: "Too many characters in character literal" is the error I get if I do this, did I do it wrong? I just copied it.

Comment: Actually in C# I think you have to use SqlParameter.  You can't just add parameters onto the end of the sql command like you're doing now.  This link should help!  http://buddylindsey.com/sql-parameters-in-c/

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and show how you could use SqlParameter.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the late reply. Your answer helped me, I've not yet got the reputation for upvoting but I selected yours as the answer, I'll rectify the situation as soon as I have the rep. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, you should do this using a StoredProc. 
Its not a solution to the prob, but another way to do this.
That way you will not face any such probs. 
Moreover, havign a StoredProc is better then constructing a query on every text change event.